# MySQL Show id of rows where column start_time, end_time value is same and count is greater than 3

Tags: mysql

I need id of each row where column start_time and end_time have same value and count of rows is equal to or greater than 3. In below table structure the id 4,7,8 have same value in start_time column, end_time column and count of row 4,7,8 is 3, so i want a query where it would only return me id 4,7,8 if count is equal to or greater than 3.

So far i came up with this query using groupby start_time and end_time, but the approach is wrong because it will only return the first id in the table when grouped by and not returning all of them.

Any Help is appreciated in advance.

**Edit**

Sorry, I forgot to mention order has a relationship with order_status_history table, the foreign key is order_id. The count should only be considered if start_time, end_time in order table is same AND in order_status_history table relevant order_id is_current = true AND status_keyword' can be any of these ['pending', 'accepted', 'on_the_way', 'assigned', 'reached', 'started'].

To sum up non of the 3 records (4,7,8) should show up, if status_key is not any of this ['pending', 'accepted', 'on_the_way', 'assigned', 'reached', 'started'] OR is_current = false.

**order_status_history Structure:**

[image]

**Query:**

```
select COUNT(*), `id`, `start_time`, `end_time` from `orders` group by `start_time`, `end_time`
```

**Result Of Above Query:**

[image]

**Table Structure:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id
FROM orders
WHERE (start_time, end_time) IN (
      SELECT start_time, end_time
      FROM orders
      GROUP BY start_time, end_time
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 3)
```

Comment: No need for concatenation: `WHERE (start_time, end_time) IN (SELECT start_time, end_time FROM ...)`

Comment: @Gonnen Daube can you please take a look at edited question, i would really appreciate it. thankyou

Comment: @Wcan this is a totally new requirement for which you should ask a new question.